# QUOTENAME alters date format

Tags: sql-server

I've got a datetime field in my table which shows dates like this:

```
2017-01-18 10:20:19.617
```

I'm using QUOTENAME to output the table with the fields wrapped in quotes so it will be compatible to import into a legacy CSV based app.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(P.CreatedOn,'"') as CreatedOn
```

That changes the output to

```
"Jan 18 2017 10:20AM"
```

Ideally I need

```
"2017-01-18 10:20:19.617"
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @Tanner, good catch :)

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick. The [CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms187928.aspx) function allows you to explicitly control the format of your date conversion.

```
declare @d datetime = '20170119 20:21:22'
select QUOTENAME(CONVERT(varchar(23), @d, 121), '"')
```

Some guidance notes:

- The style parameter 121 indicates the date/time must be formatted in the ODBC format which is `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss[.ttt[tttt]][{+|-}offset]`. It always includes the fractions of a second at 3 or 7 digits depending on the date type of the value to be converted.
- This supports all datatypes combining date & time: datetime, datetime2 (7 digit fraction of a second), smalldatetime, datetimeoffset
- date and time datatypes exclude time a date portions from the string respectively.
- Refer to the linked page to experiment with other conversion styles. E.g. style 120 is similar, but excludes the optional fractions of a second from the format.
- Note that if the the `varchar(...)` target type is to short to hold the full string, it will be truncated from the right.

Comment: might be useful to OP and future readers to state that format 121 = yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm(24h)

Comment: ***NB:*** Please bear in mind that in spite of the predictability of the converted datetime string's format: 1) ***do not*** use it for date manipulation - use the available date/time functions; 2) and avoid it for transferring dates to applications - there should be an appropriate interface layer that knows how to deal with interfacing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTENAME` returns `nvarchar (258)`. When you are supplying `DATE` to the function it does conversion to `nvarchar`.

If you convert to `varchar` or `nvarchar` first (as @CraigYoung suggesting), then this function will not do conversion itself and will not change the string.

In `CONVERT` you can specify any format you want for your date to be in using list available formats.